# how to make a portable version of chrome for testing for linux

Tags: python, google-chrome, testing, chrome-for-testing

After downloading chrome for testing from the official channel, I tried running it on my WSL2 as a test for work but it seems that it requires certain dependencies. Is there any way to create a portable version of it with all required dependencies? It being installed without its dependencies seems absurd but it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing/issues/55) for that in the [Chrome for Testing bug tracker](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing/).

In the meantime, there's a workaround in this other question: [How to install Chrome for Testing from zip file on Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76730257/how-to-install-chrome-for-testing-from-zip-file-on-debian).